# Mass Effect Andromeda: tiller quest elite destroyer invincible?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I'm playing Mass Effect Andromeda, on planet H-047c, doing the quest called "The Remnant Tiller".

In the final room with the elite destroyer, what I can do is snipe him from afar and kill both of his turrets, no problem. But after that the guy is completely invincible, as shooting / tech power / biotic power whatever does ZERO damage to him. His shield never goes down, not by one bit.

I thought maybe he can't be killed from too far away, so I would run closer and he starts moving around and attacking me. Still, invincible.

Is this a new bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try reloading? This kind of bug happened to me a few times, but usually just closing the game and reloading fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just encountered this bug myself, but I still found a way to defeat it. I happened to have the Remnant VI skill and found that it was still able to deal damage even though I was unable to. In particular I did the following:

1. Told my allies to take cover in the hallway leading to the final room.
2. Took cover at the end of the hallway. I did not wake up the progenitor from here.
3. Took out the progenitor's turrets (it never woke up, not sure if that was related to the bug) and the other enemies
4. Activated the Remnant VI and watched it attack the dormant progenitor until its shields were gone.
5. Once the shields were gone I noticed I was able to damage its base health, so I helped the VI finish off the dormant progenitor.
6. Victory!

Comment: Wow talk about a belated answer =) I totally stopped playing Andromena already but this makes me want to reinstall and reload my saves, haha. Thanks man, I don't know if this will work for me but gonna mark it the right answer.

Comment: You’re welcome! I don’t know what compelled me to pick this game up again recently to complete the rest of the missions, either way the more tips available online the better. Step 1 may not be needed but I noted it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

It is either one of the two, you are doing the boss incorrectly or it is bugged.

In-case of the [first](https://www.polygon.com/mass-effect-andromeda-guide-walkthrough/2017/4/11/15260658/the-remnant-tiller-h-047c):

> Turn right, and take out the remnant bots you find there. There’s a
>   destroyer, so be careful. Reminder: Take out the turrets on the left
>   and right side of its torso first, then just unload into its chest.

another source you can [use](http://guides.gamepressure.com/masseffectandromeda/guide.asp?ID=40179)

In-case of the second one:
Try a reload , just from the last checkpoint, or if a save from the just before the mission.